# Flutter audioplayers next and previous

Tags: flutter, package, android-music-player, flutter-audioplayers

I creating a music player in flutter using audioplayers as package but couldn't find way to play next and previous song in the list.

Comment: Add codes of what you have tried so far

Comment: @KaushikChandru I just need reference to docs which i couldn't find for playing next and previous in audioplayers package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example lets say you have a list of audio files

```dart
List<String> allAudio = [
'https://luan.xyz/files/audio/coins.wav', 
 'https://luan.xyz/files/audio/laser', 
 'https://luan.xyz/files/audio/ambient_c_motion.mp3', 
 'https://luan.xyz/files/audio/nasa_on_a_mission.mp3'
];
```

Now create an index to know which element is the current index

```dart
int index = 0;
```

Noe to change the source of the audio you just have to call

```dart
    await player.setSource(allAudio[index]);
```

And set state.. when the next button is clicked add one to the index and call the above-mentioned code to set source..

Make sure you dont increment if the length of list -1 is achieved ..

You can use this package

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: Thank you @KaushikChandru it works fine but couldn't find their documentation helpful, mostly outdated ones are there.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. yeah they only added setSource for players. Please accept my answer if it was helpful